# Post Slug does not show

Tags: php, slug, laravel-5.6

I was showing my posts using the post_id, the I followed the current docummentation to show my posts using the slug. When I create the post I see the slug is added on the database as well.
When I click on my link to view the post, it takes me to the post using the slug. However I nothing shows but this error that I had never seen before:

Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\post.blade.php)

This is my post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
class Post extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'user_id','category_id','photo_id'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/post/{slug}', ['as'=>'home.post', 
uses'=>'AdminPostsController@post']);
```

The post function from the AdminPostsController looks like this:´

```
public function post($slug){
        $post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->get();

       // $posts = Post::all();
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('post', compact('post','categories'));
 }
```

In the view I have this:

```
<h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about compact it returns an array and from you error staring also it is clear that you are trying to get object out of an array.

Try this in your view

{{ $post['title'] }}

Check if you get value ...

Comment: Does not seem to be the issue cause I get this error:
Undefined index: title (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\post.blade.php)

Comment: Just a reminder that it was working when I used the id...Only after trying to use the sluggable it started the error

Comment: Check {{ $post->slug }}, it will give you the title

Comment: "Property [slug] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\post.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0):

I browsed through github and then figured that the error was in the  get() that I was using in the controller. Because I only want one value I must use the first() instead.

```
$post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->first();
```